# Attach SQL server 2000 db in 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have MDF file of SQL Server 2000 and I dont have 2000 but visual studio 2008 i want to attach this mdf to my studio 2008 how can I do that. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you have SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Yes I have visual studio 2008. Is there any third party tool which can generate sql script from MDF file so that script I can used to generate

Comment: Just to be clear - you want to generate a database project from the contents of the MDF file?

Comment: I have a db which was generated on 2000 means i have MDF and LOG files of this db now i want to attach this SQLserver 2008 bc the application is using visual studio 2008 and need to migrate from 2000 to 2008 so if i can generate script from this MDF i can use that script as back up and run this on 2008 that will generate me the db in 2008. Is there any other options for me to use this 2000 db in 2008??

Answer (score 1):

OK - you should be able to attach the SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2008.  You can do this through the SQL Server Management Studio interface or via a script against the 2008 server.

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE db ON PRIMARY 
   (FILENAME = 
      'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\db.mdf')
   LOG ON (FILENAME = 
      'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\db_log.ldf')
   FOR ATTACH;
GO
```

Substitute your database name and file paths.  When you do the attach, the database will be upgraded to a SQL Server 2008 database, but will remain in SQL 2000 Compatibility mode.

Here's a link with more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189625.aspx